# How to get JMeter to run multiple actions for each of N users with tokens

Tags: jmeter

I'm still a noob with JMeter and I have a scenario in which I have X types of actions that I want to do with 100 users and I want to perform those actions 100 times for each type for each user. All of it using a csv file for the user list and one csv file for each type of action containing an action for each line.
The users use a Bearer token to authenticate, so I have to login with each user and take their token.
I'm having a problem that I want to take one token for one user and run the 100 actions for one type, then 100 actions for all of the other types for all of the 100 users.
The ways I tried to structure my test plan does not seem to work for what I want to achieve, I'm always ending up with some users getting skipped, a set of actions being done 2 or more times using the same user token.
My structure is basically this (I tried and altered a bunch of times so I will post the basic skeleton):

- Test Plan

  - Test Plan

    - Header Manager
    - Request Defaults
    - CSV with users credentials
    - Thread Group

      - Login Request

        - JSON Extractor (to get token)
      - Header Manager (to set token)
      - CSV list with the first type of action
      - Request for the action
      - CSV list with the second type of action
      - Request for the action
      - CSV list and request for all of the other actions and actions types

I've tried using loop, while, once only controllers but with no success. I also use the number of threads for the thread group the same as the numbers of users I want (in this case, 100) 
If anyone can help me I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread;** properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

It means that passing a token between threads is not possible (unless you're explicitly doing it yourself using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

So the only thing which comes to my mind is incorrect configuration of the CSV Data Set Config. Here is default setup:

[image]

which means that:

- **each user will read next line on each iteration** (controllable by [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) setting)
- **when the end of file is reached - it starts over from the beginning** (controllable by "Recycle on EOF" setting)

if you didn't change the default settings - it's quite expected that you have duplicate actions given you have number of loops higher than the number of lines in a CSV file.

Another possible reason is overwriting the same variable (i.e. `${action}`) by different CSV Data Set Configs, you might want to check the variables values at each step using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

Comment: I'm trying to use the token for each user to perform the action.  When I run the test with the same number of users that I have on csv it works well this part, the problem is after that, in which I set right beneath the login, the action request and use the user token but it always gets only the last one. For example, 
- Running 4threads, results tree: Login OK, Login OK, ACTION 1 OK, LOGIN OK, LOGIN OK, ACTION 1, ACTION 1....
Jmeter do not run one after the other, so the last 2 action 1 are getting the token from the last login, and not each action getting the token of each login. Ty btw